# Catch block removing objects from list on 404 responses

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I am using resttemplate to access an external api, this is my service class :

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class MusicBrainzService {

  private final String ARTIST_URL = "http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/";
  private final String PARAMS_URL = "?&fmt=json&inc=release-groups";
  private Artist artist;
  private Album album;
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  private List<Album> oldAlbumList;
  private List<Album> newAlbumList;
  private List<Image> images;

  @Autowired
  private CoverArtService coverArtService;


  public Artist fetchArtist(String mbid) {

    restTemplate = HttpRequestFactoryService.createRestTemplate();
    artist = restTemplate.getForObject(ARTIST_URL + mbid + PARAMS_URL, Artist.class);

    oldAlbumList = artist.getAlbums();
    System.out.println(oldAlbumList.size());
    newAlbumList = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < oldAlbumList.size(); i++) {
        album = oldAlbumList.get(i);
        images = coverArtService.fetchCoverArtImageUrl(album.getId().toString());
        album.setImages(images);
        newAlbumList.add(album);
      }
   } catch (final HttpClientErrorException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStatusCode() + "|" +  album.getId().toString());
    }
    artist.setAlbums(newAlbumList);

    System.out.println(newAlbumList.size());

    return artist;
  }
}
```

And my CoverArtService :

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class CoverArtService {

  private final String COVER_ART_URL = "http://coverartarchive.org/release-group/";
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  private CoverArt coverArt;


  public List<Image> fetchCoverArtImageUrl(String mbid) {

    restTemplate = HttpRequestFactoryService.createRestTemplate();

    coverArt = restTemplate.getForObject(COVER_ART_URL + mbid, CoverArt.class);

    List<Image> images = coverArt.getImages();

    return images;
  }
```

My Album entity :

```
  private UUID id;
  private String title;
  @JsonProperty("first-release-date")
  private String firstReleaseDate;
  private List<Image> images;

  public Album() {
  }

  public Album(UUID id, String title, String firstReleaseDate, List<Image> images) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.firstReleaseDate = firstReleaseDate;
    this.images = images;
  }
  
  //Getters and setters..
```

My CoverArt entity :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CoverArt {

  private List<Image> images;

  public CoverArt() {
  }

  public CoverArt(List<Image> images) {
    this.images = images;
  }

//Getters and setters
```

My Image entity :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Image {

  @JsonProperty("image")
  private String imageURL;

  public Image() {
  }

  public Image(String imageURL) {
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}

//Getters and setters..
```

Some of the images don't have valid image urls, on these I want to return null as imageUrl.
However , an exception is thrown when response is 404, I fixed this by adding a try catch block.

But it seems as if the albums who don't have a valid image url gets removed from the list.
I don't want to remove them, I simply want to set the imageUrl to null whenever the exception is thrown, is this possible?

Comment: I think you can handle that if you try/catch around this call:  `coverArt = restTemplate.getForObject` in your `fetchCoverArtImageUrl` method.  My suspicion is that you're not just missing albums that throw a 404, you're missing all the albums after the first to throw a 404. (i.e. you're handling the exception outside the loop, and you need to catch it inside the loop)

Comment: Thank you , now it seems to include all albums even with the ones that throw 404!

Comment: Now it seems as if the ones that return 404 get the imageUrl of the previous album that returned 200, how do I make these values null?